# Check if SVG Paths are next to eachother?

Tags: javascript, php, svg

So i have these regions made out of SVG Paths. 
[image]

I need a way to calculate shared borders. Is there a nice way to take the d="" values from 2 path´s, and match them up against eachother?, and if they have a similar coordinate +/- some margin for errors if they aint exactly identical?

This will be done server-side and not client side, not sure if it matters :)

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: seems like some useful search results come up when searching for "svc adjacency"

Comment: Maybe im blind, but none of the answers i found were able to calculate this? :)

Comment: The [intersection library](http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/) can help with that.

Comment: Some of these shapes aint overlapping eachother thou, so the Intersection Library would not work here?, unless i tweaked the library to allow for almost overlapping hehe, any thoughts Lars?

Comment: Getting closer to solution, will update once its finished.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ive now found a solution that works for me. Still a lot optimization, but wanted to share my approach.

Im storing SVG Data in a database, so my use may not be identical to others, but the approach could be the same.

Step 1: Store all d="" attributes for each svg path, its important that all coordinates are stored in Absolute, so im running the [Snap.Path.ToAbsolute](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.path.toAbsolute) function from  pre-database insert:

```
$('#Test').click(function () {
    $('path').each( function() {
        pathh = (this).getAttribute('d');
        pathAbs = Snap.path.toAbsolute(pathh);
        console.log(pathh);
        this.setAttribute('d', pathAbs);
    });
});
```

Step 2: Now i am taking all the path d attributes i previously put into the database and pulling them even further apart, storing each coordinate with longitude and latitude in a seperate table with a relation to the original path id.

```
function GetRegionCoords($String, $Path) {

global $main;

$output = preg_split( "/(M|L|Z|C|A|z)/", $String );

$output = array_filter($output);

foreach ($output as $coord) {
    $latNlong = explode(",", $coord);

    $query = "INSERT INTO path_coords (RegionID, Latitude, Longitude) VALUES ('$RegionID', '$latNlong[0]', '$latNlong[1]')";
    $result = mysqli_query($main, $query);

}
```

Step 3: At this stage its simply a matter of selecting all entries and compare their longitude and latitude value, and if their within a certain range (Not exact as humans got errors, and points isent always exactly on top of eachother), then their neighbors.

This is very early stage of this code, so i apologize for any errors, but now others have the chance to atleast see my approach to this.

I tested this on the middle region here to find its neighbors, and my code found all of them: [image]

So its perfect for me.

Thanks for suggestions.